# How can I set the nodeID of a YARN NodeManager?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to set up a custom Hadoop infrastructure on EC2 Spot Instances by the help of Ansible. Inside such an instance, only the internal IP is known. Luckily, there is an `ec2.py` script that dynamically generates an inventory and can be configured to use the full external DNS name of the instances as `inventory_hostname`. So I set up all Jinja2 templates to use `inventory_hostname` to set the configuration XML files. This works so far for HDFS, and for YARN, the Nodemanagers are also registered with the Resource manager.

However, the nodeIDs are set incorrectly, i.e., to their internal IP addresses.

My yarn-site.xml.j2 looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>{{resourcemanager_fqdn}}</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>{{resourcemanager_fqdn}}:8032</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>{{resourcemanager_fqdn}}:8030</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>{{resourcemanager_fqdn}}:8088</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>{{resourcemanager_fqdn}}:8031</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>{{resourcemanager_fqdn}}:8033</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>{{inventory_hostname}}</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
        <value>{{inventory_hostname}}:9999</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address</name>
        <value>{{inventory_hostname}}:8040</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>{{inventory_hostname}}:8042</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.bind-host</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

where the variable `resourcemanager_fqdn` is obtained like this:

```
{{hostvars[groups['tag_hadoop_resourcemanager'][0]].inventory_hostname}}
```

`tag_hadoop_resourcemanager` is a dynamically generated hostgroup of `ec2.py`.

I thought the node id is derived from `yarn.nodemanager.address`, but this seems to be ignored. Only the port 9999 is taken into account.

Is this a bug or did I forget to set an additional option?

Comment: Could you give values of: `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` and `yarn.nodemanager.address` for 1 Node Manager?

Comment: `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` correctly points to the external hostname of the resource manager, and `yarn.nodemanager.address` is correctly set to `ec2-aa-bb-cc-dd.compute-1.amazonws.com:9999`, i.e., the external hostnames and port 9999.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand correctly, yarn.nodemanager.hostname is getting set incorrectly to internal IP.

Comment: Exactly. Should I file a JIRA for this?

Comment: I need to check the code, to be 100% sure. I'll check the code. Not sure, if its a bug

Comment: Any reason not to use EMR for easier Hadoop cluster setup?

Comment: @rabejens This is not a bug. I have added an answer. Please check, if it works for you.

Comment: @Guy: I want a special setup which incorporates Spark on YARN, a Cassandra database and Kafka. Plus, I want to re-use the Ansible playbook with some minor variations at work where we are not allowed to use EC2/AWS but have an internal solution for virtual machines.

Comment: Talking about heavy lifting... Spark can be set up with one flag on EMR. DynamoDB and Kinesis are available in one API call. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I know this, but as I said, I am just using AWS to prepare the playbook at home which I later want to use at work in a non-EC2 environment.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the YARN code and found out the following.

There is a function `buildNodeId()`, which builds the Node Id.

Node Id is a combination of `host` and `port` and it is set to `host:port`.

`buildNodeId()` internally calls the following function to get the `InetAddress`:

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
```

This call always returns internal IP address as the first IP address.

Let me explain with an example.
For e.g. I have following IPs:

```
Ethernet: 172.23.206.41 (External IP)
Host-Only: 192.168.56.1 (Internal IP).
```

Let me explain the 2 cases (internal vs external IP)

- Case 1: Default to internal IP

  I set the following in my `yarn-site.xml`:

  ```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
      <value>mballur:9999</value>
  </property>
  ```

  Where `mballur` is my host name.

  Now, when I run `yarn node -list -all`, I get the Node ID as below:

  ```
  Total Nodes:1
  Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
  192.168.56.1:9999   RUNNING    192.168.56.1:50060  0
  ```

  Node ID is combination of internal IP + port. Because, `InetAddress.getByName(host)`, returns the internal IP as the first IP address.
- Case 2: Explicitly specify the external IP

  I set the following in my `yarn-site.xml`:

  ```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
      <value>172.23.206.41:9999</value>
  </property>
  ```

  Where `172.23.206.41` is my external IP.

  Now, when I run `yarn node -list -all`, I get the Node ID as below:

  ```
  Total Nodes:1
  Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
  172.23.206.41:9999  RUNNING    172.23.206.41:50060 0
  ```

  Now, Node ID is combination of "external IP + port".

Comment: For me, this does not work. When I set `yarn.nodemanager.address` to `ec2-aa-bb-cc-dd.compute-1.amazonws.com:9999:9999`, a `yarn node -list -all` outputs the internal IP address. But since `InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);` is used, it is clear why. The external IP address and public DNS is not known in the VM. Amazon does some sort of NAT to route to the VM. It is similar to the network at home, where all devices have an IP in some 192.168 range, but the ISP assigns an external IP... Continued in next comment

Comment: ... and thus `InetAddress.getByName(host)` cannot get this external one. I will try to put an appropriate entry into `/etc/hosts` and update `/etc/hostname` to the public DNS name and see if it works. However, there should be a configuration option which allows to specify whether `InetAddress.getByName(host)` or the information from `yarn.nodemanager.address` is to be used. So it is technically not a bug, but could be an enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this. I have to make my instances think their host name is the external DNS name.

This is how I got it to work:

First, I created a role named `rewrite_hosts`, which contains only a `tasks` directory and in this `tasks` directory the following `main.yml`:

```
---
- name: "/etc/hostname must contain external DNS"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  shell: echo {{inventory_hostname}} >/etc/hostname
- name: "Determine external IP"
  shell: wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
  register: host_ip
- name: "/etc/hosts entry must exist pointing to external IP"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/hosts line="{{host_ip.stdout}} {{inventory_hostname}}" state=present
- name: "Update current hostname"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  shell: hostname $(cat /etc/hostname)
```

Then, I set up ec2.py [as described here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/). However, I changed two things in `ec2.ini`:

- Set `vpc_destination_variable = public_dns_name` (otherwise, it would use the IP address)
- Added `rds = false` because I do not use RDS instances. YMMV on this.

Then, before setting up anything hadoop-specific, I added the following into my playbook:

```
- name: "Update IP information"
  hosts: tag_origin_ec2
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: ubuntu
  roles:
  - rewrite_hosts
```

I tag my instances with `origin: ec2` because I later want to re-use most of the playbook in a non-EC2 environment, so this part will simply get skipped.

All subsequent plays in the playbook will then work as expected with `ansible_fqdn`. However be careful with `ansible_eth0.ipv4.address` as this gets the internal address from eth0. As a workaround, use the following task:

```
- name: "Determine external IP"
  shell: wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
  register: host_ip
```

Then, you can use `host_ip.stdout` to obtain the IP address if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you thought is right, what you should do include:

1, set `dfs.datanode.hostname` of `hdfs-site.xml` to your `public DNS name`.

2, add the mapping between `public DNS name` and local ip to the `/etc/hosts` of each node them self, this rules must appear in front of the mapping between `hostname` and local ip.

3, set the `dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname` and `dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname` of `hdfs-site.xml` on every node to `true`.